# Additional information: This row already belongs to this table.

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que busca informações em um excel e faz alguns tratamentos para salvar os dados em um banco DBF. 
Todos os tratamentos que faço são em cima de DataTables, logo utilizo dataRows e depois de um certo tempo, estou enfrentando muitos problemas com o seguinte erro "Additional information: This row already belongs to this table."

Já pesquisei algumas soluções, mas fiz uma query entre dois dataTables.

```
var dtJoin = from dtOri in dbCons.getDataTable("\\ArqDbf.DBF").AsEnumerable()
             join dtFKey in dbCons.getDataTable("\\ArqDbf.DBF").AsEnumerable()
             on dtOri["prnt_ent"] equals dtFKey["org_ent_id"]
             select dtJoinOrg.LoadDataRow(new object[]
             {
                 dtOri["org_ent_id"],
                 dtOri["org_ent_nm"],
                 dtOri["org_en_des"],
                 dtOri["prnt_ent"],
                 dtFKey["org_ent_nm"],
                 dtFKey["org_en_des"]  
             },false);

dtOrgs.TableName = "Orgs";
foreach (DataRow drJoin in dtJoin)
{
    dtJoinOrg.Rows.Add(drJoin);
}
```

E no ponto em que faço o "dtJoinOrg.Rows.Add" ele da esse erro, mas aonde que o dataRow está vinculado a um dataTable? Como posso resolver esse problema?

Sobre ao dataRow pertencer a um dataTable, eu criei a seguinte solução:

```
/*
    Nesse caso o pDtClone tem a mesma estrutura do pDtOri. 
    Caso alguem se pergunte por que estou fazendo isso, 
    é que há um tratamento durante a execução em que poderei alterar as 
    informações do pDtClone e depois vou comparar com o pDtOri
*/
DataRow[] drResult = pDtOri.Select(vWhere);

if (drResult.Length > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < drResult.Length; i++)
    {
        DataRow drNew = pDtClone.NewRow();
        try
        {
            int vColIndex = 0;
            foreach (object vValue in drResult[0].ItemArray)
            {
                drNew[vColIndex] = vValue;
                vColIndex++;
            }
            pDtClone.Rows.Add(drNew);
        }
        finally
        {
            drNew = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Isso até o momento é uma solução que achei, mas gostaria de ver outras soluções.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não se pode inserir uma linha mais de uma vez em uma tabela.

O `DataTable` é uma representação de tabela relacional de banco de dados, então, cada linha, além das colunas que foram definidas, existe um identificador interno que torna cada linha única, independente das colunas ou seus valores.

No seu `select` já está incluindo as linhas usando o `LoadDataRow()`. Se verificar com o QuickWatch verá que as linhas já estão lá, e está tentando reinseri-las. Talvez falte apenas salvar os dados com o `SaveState()` do `DataTable`.

Por último, recomendo parar de usar `DataTable`. Se existe possibilidade de trabalhar apenas com enumeradores, use apenas eles com `Linq` e expressão Lambda.

Eu cheguei a escrever um artigo desencorajando a usar `DataTable`, você pode [ler o artigo aqui](http://thiagolunardi.net/2015/03/datatable-a-inimiga-oculta/).

Comment: Entendi, realmente... no meu caso, eu poderia trocar a maior parte dos `dataTables` por `Lists`, obrigado pelo artigo e pela resposta